# Как вернуться в начало цикла?

Tags: c++, for

у меня есть код, меня интересует именно вот этот кусок:

```
while(true)
    {
        if((k - n_d[l1] == 0) || (k - n_d[l1] == -1 ))
        {
             if(l1 == r)
            {
                cout << count;
                break;
            }
            if(l1 != r)
            {
                k = k_old;
                count -= 1;
                n_d[count2] = 1;
                count2 += 1;
                continue;
                //Вот здесь мне нужно вернуться в начало цикла и проделать все заново
            }
        }

         if(k - n_d[l1] > 0)
        {
            k = k - n_d[l1];
            l1 += 1;
        }
    }
```

Не могу понять правильно я сделал или нет, если нет то подскажите как правильно)
Спасибо заранее!

Comment: Я хочу чтобы при условии если **l1 !=  r** я возвращался в начало **while** и проходил вычисления заново

Comment: Откуда же нам знать "как правильно"? Это только вам известно, какие у вас должны быть значения (и где) в начале цикла. На эти ваши магические значения ничего не говорят.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не ясно выразился. Вопрос такой - если я пишу **continue** меня перебросит в начало цикла while?

Comment: @Просто Кодер: `continue ` перебрасывает вас на **конец** тела цикла, а не на начало. В цикле `while` это действительно эквивалентно переходу на начало цикла. В остальных видах циклов - в общем случае не эквивалентно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете упростить до:

```
while (l1 != r)
{
    if (k > n_d[l1])
    {
        k = k - n_d[l1];
        l1 += 1;
    }
    else
    {           
        k = k_old;
        count -= 1;
        n_d[count2] = 1;
        count2 += 1;            
    }       
}
cout << count;
```

Учитывая количество участвующих обьектов, подозреваю, что весь код нуждается пересмотру

Comment: Странно, если вы упростили мой код, не меняя его. Я его вставил вместо своего и все заработало... Хмм, пойду разбираться в упрощение этого куска, спасибо большое)

Comment: @Просто Кодер, это вам кажется, что ничего не изменилось. Я просто выразил то, что вы хотели, а вы своим кодом даже компилятору можете заставить запутаться(в качестве шутки)